# How to use FormatConditions to change the cell color based on the compare of cell value with other cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to change the cell color if the cell value is bigger than another cell in other column. for example value in G6 > D6, and this rule need to apply to the whole column.

I used formatConditions implemented some code, but the result is not very correct.

```
 Set rngCell = Cells(6, 7)

 Set objCF = rngCell.FormatConditions.Add _
            (Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, Formula1:=rngCell.offset(, -3))
'set formats for new CF
With objCF
    .Font.ColorIndex = 26
    .Interior.ColorIndex = 19
End With
```

With this code , I got the result rule is: Cell Value > 18 (18 is the cell value of D6)

But what I want is rule like: Cell value > $D6

Anyone can help?

Comment: You need to use Type:=xlExpression.  Also, see this link for an issue you'll likely run into http://support.microsoft.com/kb/895562

Comment: @TimWilliams: Sorry didn't see your comment. The crossover was unintentional.

Comment: Also thanks Tim for your suggestion, today don't get time to try your solution. I will try it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the method I used (you can easily create and modify one using the Macro Recorder). The formatting will be applied to the seventh column ("G"). The formula is self-explanatory. Note that since the formula is a string you can concatenate the columns / rows dynamically.

```
Dim r As Range

Set r = Sheet1.Columns(7)
r.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$G1>$D1"
r.FormatConditions(r.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With r.FormatConditions(1)
    .Interior.PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Interior.ColorIndex = 19
    .Font.ColorIndex = 26
End With
r.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

set r = nothing
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, I tried, but using this the format of whole column will change if the condition is true. this is not what I expect.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing if for just that cell then try this

```
Set rngCell = Cells(6, 7)

Set objCF = rngCell.FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, _
                                         Operator:=xlGreater, _
                                         Formula1:="=" & rngCell.Address & ">" & rngCell.Offset(, -3).Address)
'set formats for new CF
With objCF
    .Font.ColorIndex = 26
    .Interior.ColorIndex = 19
End With
```

If you are doing it for the entire column then try this

```
Set rngCell = Cells(1, 7)

Set objCF = Columns("G:G").FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, _
                                         Operator:=xlGreater, _
                                         Formula1:="=" & Replace(rngCell.Address, "$", "") & _
                                         ">" & Replace(rngCell.Offset(, -3).Address, "$", ""))
'set formats for new CF
With objCF
    .Font.ColorIndex = 26
    .Interior.ColorIndex = 19
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm still trying... using this way, the rule I generated is something like :=L1048557>I1048557 , I don't know why, what I want to compare is the G and D column.

Comment: Can I generate the rule like: Cell Value > $D6, then I can apply this rule to all the column, because it works well if I manually add this rule to my worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the input, maybe I didn't describe my question correctly. what I want is only change the color of one cell in column G, for instance the value $G$9 > $D$9, then I only need to change the format of cell G9, the same rule for the whole column(exclude the four head rows).

Now I have worked out one solution, currently it works fine.

```
Dim r As Range
Set r = Cells(5, 7)
r.FormatConditions.Delete
r.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, Formula1:="=$D5"
r.FormatConditions(r.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With r.FormatConditions(1)
    .Interior.PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Interior.ColorIndex = 19
    .Font.ColorIndex = 26
End With
r.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

r.Copy
Range("G5:G" & lastRowNum).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
```